# Как сделать задержку между асинхронными запросами в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Необходимо во внутреннем цикле отсылать запрос через каждые 1 сек, а во внешнем задержка 15 сек.

То есть отсылается часть запросов через каждые 1 сек, потом задержка 15 сек и потом другая часть запросов через 1 сек между ними.

Пробовал через setInterval(), но сначала проходит весь цикл, и потом сразу все запросы разом отсылаются.

Как решить проблему?

```
 function start_job(tickets_list, job_list) {

    for(let i=0; i < tickets_list.length; i++) {

       for(let j=0; j < job_list.length; j++) {
          let uri = 'https://some_address' + tickets_list[i];
          let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          let str = job_list[j];
          xhr.open('PUT', uri, true);   
          xhr.send(str);
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function start_job(tickets_list, job_list) {
   for(let i=0; i < tickets_list.length; i++) {
     for(let j=0; j < job_list.length; j++) {
       setTimeout(function() {
         let uri = 'https://some_address' + tickets_list[i];
         let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         let str = job_list[j];
         xhr.open('PUT', uri, true);   
         xhr.send(str);
       }, (i * 15 + j + 1) * 1000);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: IE 11 ругается на стрелочные функции.

Comment: @МихаилКрыгин Замените их на обычные.

Answer (score 1):

Если можете превратить функцию в асинхронную, можно так:

```js
function wait(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => { setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000); });
}

async function start_job(tickets_list, job_list) {

  for(let i=0; i < tickets_list.length; i++) {

    for(let j=0; j < job_list.length; j++) {
      let uri = 'https://some_address' + tickets_list[i];
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      let str = job_list[j];
      xhr.open('PUT', uri, true);
      xhr.send(str);

      await wait(1);
    }

    await wait(15);
  }
}
```